# How to log output foreachPartition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, I am using foreachPartition(makeHTTPRequests) to post requests to transfer data by partitions. Considering that foreachPartition is on the worker node, how do I collect the responses? (I know print only works on worker node logs)

The structure of my code looks like this:

```py
def add_scores(spark, XXXXXX):
    headers = login()
    results = ResultsModels(spark) # to get sparksql model
    scores = results.get_scores(execution_id)
    scores = scores.repartition("id")
    url = "XXXXXXX"
    scores.foreachPartition(make_score_api_call(url, headers))

def make_score_api_call(url, headers):
    def make_call_function(rows):
        payload = []
        for row in rows:
            rowdict = row.asDict()
            rowdict['rules_aggregation'] = json.loads(row.asDict()['rules_aggregation'])
            payload.append(rowdict)
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.text) 

    return make_call_function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use log4j , and as log4j isnt serielizable (necessary to log from executors) you should use it like this:

```
object LogHolder extends Serializable { // object to log within the executors
    @transient lazy val log = LogManager.getRootLogger // @transient lazy makes so it only initilized when you use it in the machine.
    log.setLevel(Level.INFO)
}
```

Once your spark job will be collected all this data will be collected. So instead of using print use this :

```
LogHolder.log.info("response status_code=" + response.status_code)
LogHolder.log.info("response text=" + response.text)
```

This will only help with logging the response if you want to collect the data let me know.